# Is there a categorification for this number theory statement?

Tags: number-theory, category-theory, determinant

I recently learnt about a very cute/interesting fact:

*Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then the determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$th entry is $\text{gcd}(i,j)$ is $\prod_{k=1}^n \varphi(k)$.*

I also have been reading a very small amount about categorification recently as I have been trying to slowly get into certain aspects of higher algebra. I wondered therefore, perhaps very naively, if this statement has a categorification: $\varphi(k)$ is the cardinality of the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ so perhaps the product will categorify into something like $⨉_{k=1}^n (\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and I know that $\text{gcd}(i,j)$ additionally has an interpretation in terms of being the generator of the sum of the ideals $i\mathbb{Z},j\mathbb{Z}$ so this seems vaguely plausible.

Is there a natural categorification or is this just wishful thinking?

Comment: Just want to point out that this result has a general form known as Smith determinant https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379596001929